# Basic page URL broken because it only consists of server address and page name, docroot path omitted

Tags: 7, uri

I have a local development server setup whereby my drupal sites are in separate folders on the server, for example:

- /var/www/site1/
- /var/www/site2/
- etc.

While most URL links work fine, ( e.g. `http://mylocalserver/site1/content/an-article` ), the basic page content type does not.

For example, if I create a basic page with (sub)URL, e.g. `terms` , note - with NO preceding slash,  `/`  then this is shown in menu links as `http://mylocalserver/terms` (which is broken) and not `http://mylocalserver/site1/terms` as I would expect.)

I have cleared the cache ( `drush cc all` ) but this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting `$base_url` in the settings.php?

Comment: +1 for your input @Steven, no I haven't but what I can't understand is why most of the other links, including clean URLs work but not just a small number of links. Surely *all* links should know how to derive their based address - if some can, why can't the others?! Also, setting the `$base_url` may not be suitable as the work will eventually be on a production server which would not require this, but then I suppose `.gitignore` containing `settings.php` would prevent overwriting the file on production.

Comment: @therobyouknow do you have Pathauto installed? What's `"(sub)URL attachment"`? Where's this coming from? I wanted to say maybe you should put `RewriteBase /site1` in your .htaccess but I stopped myself because if other content types are working it's more likely a module issue.

Comment: @Beebee - sorry yes, correction: `(sub)URL attachment` should read: `(sub)URL` - as in terms is the sub URL of `http://mylocalserver/site1/terms` (where `http://mylocalserver/site1/` is the base URL - as Drupal states in `admin/config/system/site-information` - if Drupal recognises it here correctly, I don't know why I would need to also set it in `$base_url` in `settings.php` !

Comment: If you want a multi site setup, you should use the same code base, different modules and themes and database if you want (you should take a look at multisite drupal setups). If you want to keep it the way it is you'll need to make sure your subdirectories have the default drupal .htaccess file in both, and make sure your site url in configuration is properly set (as well as base_url). Most likely Drupal is picking up the wrong URL somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Steven for your input! site url in configuration is properly set - yes, base_url - setting this makes no difference to the problem. "Most likely Drupal is picking up the wrong URL somewhere." - yes, for some cases. Wish I could pinpoint where.